# AWS Lambda Memory Vs CPU configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

In AWS lambda environment we can specify only the memory configuration. Is there any documentation as to what the CPU config will be for a given memory configuration?

For example,

```
  ApiLambda:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Description: "This function handles the example"
      CodeUri: "./app/"
      Handler: "app.handle_request"
      MemorySize: 128
      Timeout: 60
      Runtime: python3.7
```

I am trying to find the minimum `MemorySize` for a particular number of cores.
Is there any way to know the boundaries of MemorySize where the `#Cores` changes without bruteforcing `MemorySize`?

Ref:

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/12/aws-lambda-supports-10gb-memory-6-vcpu-cores-lambda-functions/
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-memory.html

Answer (score 81, accepted):

The official thresholds are:

- 1 vCPU for 1,769 MB ([ref](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-memory.html))
- 6 vCPUs for  10,240 MB ([ref](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/12/aws-lambda-supports-10gb-memory-6-vcpu-cores-lambda-functions/))

Recent [study](https://web.archive.org/web/20220629183438/https://www.sentiatechblog.com/aws-re-invent-2020-day-3-optimizing-lambda-cost-with-multi-threading?utm_source=reddit&utm_medium=social&utm_campaign=day3_lambda) (archive link) concludes the following for what is happening in-between:

[image]

Update 09/2023:

An archive link to the [study](https://web.archive.org/web/20220629183438/https://www.sentiatechblog.com/aws-re-invent-2020-day-3-optimizing-lambda-cost-with-multi-threading?utm_source=reddit&utm_medium=social&utm_campaign=day3_lambda) quoted is used, as original link does not work.

Comment: The linked docu says "At 1,769 MB, a function has the equivalent of one vCPU (one vCPU-second of credits per second)." however, you show in the table 2vCPU. Can you elaborate, please?

Comment: @agoldev  The table is from a third party study of that. I updated the answer with archive link as original link does not work.

Answer (score 3):

#### Allocated cores by memory

In addition to @Marcin's reply, according to [Chris Munns's presentation at AWS re:Invent 2020: What’s new in serverless](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aW5EtKHTMuQ&t=339s), you can have the following allocated cores for your Lambda (which is also mentioned in [AWS Documentation > Lambda > Configuring function memory (console)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-function-common.html#configuration-memory-console)):

| Configured Memory (MB) | Allocated cores |
| --- | --- |
| 128-1769 | 1 |
| 1770-3538 | 2 |
| 3539-5307 | 3 |
| 5308-7076 | 4 |
| 7077-8845 | 5 |
| 8846-10240 | 6 |

#### Allocated computing power by memory (CPU Cap)

Also, [AWS Documentation > Lambda > Memory and computing power](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/operatorguide/computing-power.html) states that "The amount of memory also determines the amount of virtual CPU available to a function. Adding more memory proportionally increases the amount of CPU, increasing the overall computational power available. If a function is CPU-, network- or memory-bound, then changing the memory setting can dramatically improve its performance."

According to the [AWS Docs > Lambda > Configuring function memory (console)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-function-common.html#:%7E:text=At%201%2C769%20MB%2C%20a%20function%20has%20the%20equivalent%20of%20one%20vCPU%20(one%20vCPU%2Dsecond%20of%20credits%20per%20second).), "At 1,769 MB, a function has the equivalent of one vCPU (one vCPU-second of credits per second)."

Supported by my own experiments, you can utilize at maximum "N/1769 * 100"% of a vCPU where N is the configured maximum memory in MB. This is what I call `CPU Cap`, the maximum percentage of a CPU core (vCPU) that can be utilized at any point in a time that is bound by memory size.

| Memory | CPU Cap |
| --- | --- |
| 192 MB | 10.8% |
| 256 MB | 14.1% |

In my experiment, I observed 38ms duration for 192MB memory (10.8% CPU Cap), and 29ms duration for 256MB memory (14.1% CPU Cap):

38ms x 10.8% CPU Cap => 410,4 unit work

410,4 unit work / 29ms => 14.1% CPU Cap

#### 10x improvement in performance with the same cost

According to [the experiment shown on the same docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/operatorguide/computing-power.html), it is mentioned that "at 128 MB, the function takes 11.722 seconds on average to complete, at a cost of $0.024628 for 1,000 invocations. When the memory is increased to 1536 MB, the duration average drops to 1.465 seconds, so the cost is $0.024638. For a one-thousandth of a cent cost difference, the function has a 10-fold improvement in performance."

| Memory | Duration | Cost |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 128 MB | 11.722 s | $0.024628 |
| 512 MB | 6.678 s | $0.028035 |
| 1024 MB | 3.194 s | $0.026830 |
| 1536 MB | 1.465 s | $0.024638 |

Comment: Doesn't look like the ranges in the first table still hold true. The one posted by Marcin does though. Just checked it myself.

Comment: Hey @DanyloStackylo, could you please share your experiment process with us so we can cross-compare? According to our study, AWS Documentation, and AWS re:Invent presentation on YouTube support the table mentioned from my point of view.

Comment: hello, @Chooti, I first relied on your table while checking the number of cores, using Java API `Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()`, and that didn't output as expected. Then I tried a "binary search" way to figure out at what memory level do I get 3 cores (that's what I needed for my particular experiment), and it turned out to be 3009 MB, while 3008 MB provided with only 2 cores.

Comment: Thanks for the information @DanyloStackylo, it is really weird for me to be honest.
According to the [AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-function-common.html#configuration-memory-console:~:text=At%201%2C769%20MB%2C%20a%20function%20has%20the%20equivalent%20of%20one%20vCPU%20(one%20vCPU%2Dsecond%20of%20credits%20per%20second)) and [Chris Munns's re:Invent 2020 Presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aW5EtKHTMuQ&t=339s&ab_channel=AWSEvents) the values in the table I shared should hold 
I am not sure what am I missing here tbh.